# First Time In and Last Time Out with Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a data below where I want to get the unique ID number and only get the first time in and last time out. The data looks something like this:

[image]

The result should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Max(IF()) and MIN(IF())

Comment: http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2011/07/27/finding-min-if-or-max-if-in-excel/

Comment: My only problem with Max and Min is that it won't treat the data as Time. It is being extracted as a text.

Comment: You will need to convert all the text to actual times.  put a space between the numbers and the AM/PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your times are text that look like times we need to convert them.

We can do this in formula using two nested SUBSTITUTES.

To get the MIN and MAX we will use the AGGREGATE formula.

MIN:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($D$2:$D$7,"AM"," AM"),"PM"," PM")/($A$2:$A$7=A12),1)
```

MAX:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($F$2:$F$7,"AM"," AM"),"PM"," PM")/($A$2:$A$7=A12),1)
```

[image]

---

You can do the same with array formulas MIN(IF()) and MAX(IF()).

```
=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$7=A12,--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($D$2:$D$7,"AM"," AM"),"PM"," PM")))
=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$7=A12,--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($F$2:$F$7,"AM"," AM"),"PM"," PM")))
```

As they are array formulas they need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

---

Both Sets of formula will return a decimal.  The cell will need to be formatted to the proper desired output.

Comment: Thank you kindly, Scott! This saved me a lot of trouble. :)